# How to split fields of model class between different views and templates to take inputs in different forms?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have a class in my **models.py** with name '**Client**', and it has different fields like (name, dob.. etc). I have a view for that called '**ClientCreateView**' in **views.py** in which I am taking input in some fields of Client class (NOT all fields). And the template for this is called '**client_form.html**'.

Related files are given below:

**models.py:**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    dob = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    CNIC = models.SlugField(max_length = 100)
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    down_payment = models.IntegerField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    installment_month = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    installment_amount = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

**views.py:**

```
class ClientCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Client
    fields = ['name', 'dob', 'CNIC', 'property_type', 'down_payment']



class AddInstallmentView(CreateView):
    model = Client
    fields = ['installment_month', 'installment_amount']
```

**client_form.html**

```
{% extends "property_details/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content_section">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Add New Client</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Client</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Now As you can see that I took the inputs in my **views.py** in the first five fields (name, dob, CNIC, property_type, down_payment), because these are the only fields required to add new client to my database.

Once client is added to database. I want to add installment for the added client. So I made a new view called '**AddInstallmentView**' (see above in views.py)

And the html form for this is '**addinstallment_form.html**' given below:

**addinstallment.html**

```
{% extends "property_details/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="content_section">
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Add New Installment</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Installment</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Now, when I run the server and I try to add the client. it works!

But when I try to add installment to the client. I see the form for that containing two fields (installment_month, installment_amount). but the legend I see is 'Add new client', which is actually the legend in '**client_form.html**' (see above), and the submit button is also from the '**client_form.html**' which is '**Add Client**', but the legend should be '**Add New Installment**', and the submit button should be '**Add Installment**'.

It seems like I just have the fields of **AddInstallmentView**, but the template is still the '**client_form.hmtl**'.

Does anyone has an idea how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### By default django look for a template_name with (modelname_form.html)

since your models is  both views are looking to the "client_form.html" you should change the  template name in the AddInstallmentView by adding

```
template_name = "path/addinstallment.html"
```

Comment: + I think it will give you an error because you should add (blank=TRUE) to 
('installment_month',)  in your models and change the AddInstallmentView to inherit from updateview instead of createview becuse you don't want to create another object but just edit an existed ones